# Multiplication of function with Dirac impulses: sketch signal

Tags: sampling, continuous-signals, dirac-delta-impulse

I should sketch the signal below:

[image]
I think I should use delta dirac function sampling theorem but I don't know how in this special case
I know that $x(t)δ(t-t_{0})=x(t_{0})δ(t-t_{0})$ but I don't have any idea about $x(t)δ(at-t_{0})$

Comment: You might find this property useful:

$$ \delta(a t) = \frac{\delta(t)}{|a|}$$

Comment: What is "delta dirac function sampling theorem"?

Comment: Are you sure this multiplication and not convolution? The delta dirac is a distribution and multiplication between a function and a distribution is mathematically iffy.

Comment: @Hilmar, is it? I wouldn't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product $x(t)\delta(at-b)$, $a\neq 0$, can be rewritten in the following way. With $\tau=at-b$ we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\delta(at-b)dt &= \frac{1}{|a|}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\left(\frac{\tau+b}{a}\right)\delta(\tau)d\tau \\& = \frac{1}{|a|}x\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

where I've assumed that $x(t)$ is continuous at $t=b/a$.

From $(1)$ it follows that

\begin{align*}
x(t)\delta(at-b) &= \frac{1}{|a|}x\left(t\right)\delta\left(t-\frac{b}{a}\right)\\ &= \frac{1}{|a|}x\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\delta\left(t-\frac{b}{a}\right)
\end{align*}

because

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\delta(at-b)dt = \frac{1}{|a|}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\delta\left(t-\frac{b}{a}\right)dt$$

Comment: Thank all of you, I got it what I wanted to solve this problem. By using $\delta(a t) = \frac{\delta(t)}{|a|}$ and Matt L. guidance I solve it